# How to make the player rotate without the camera itself rotate while the camera follow the player in unity in 2D?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a shooting 2D top down view, so the player would face the direction the of the mouse, I am following some tutorials in youtube but none of them shows how to do this specifically from my question. Another thing I want is to make the camera a child of the player object. My player's script is currently like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    Vector2 movement;
    Vector2 mousePos;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Camera cam;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.Log(mousePos);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;

        rb.rotation = angle;
    }
}
```

I was following this guy in youtube for this code:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNLVOjbrQj4&t=584s

The difference between what he did and what I want to do is that I am trying to make the camera follow the player at the same time, while the camera doesn't rotate and he doesn't do that.

Comment: well by child'ing it, it will do that, its a bit like if you mvoe the front of your face the back of your head moves too you cant stop it.  The easiest way to do it is for the camera not to be a child and just have it follow..

Comment: You can make the camera a child of the player object and then adjust its position and rotation accordingly. Have the camera's position set to match the player's position in the fixed update method. Makes the camera follow the player. Since the camera is a child of the player object, it will move relative to the player's position.